# prevent google chrome window from bouncing automatically make the mouse pointer point itself on screen and when opening new tabs or navigate

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using selenium on google chrome and have a rather annoying problem like this: every time I do tasks like opening a new tab or navigating to a url, the window browser shows and pops up my screen. is there any way i don't allow it to turn on by itself or let it run in the background but not use headless mode(
icon still in the taskbar, but not set pó out off the screen because even when it's off my screen the mouse pointer always points to chrome every time it is active).

I want to fix this because i tried to set chrome size out of screen but when i'm typing text every time
it only mouse mouse to chrome when it work and it annoys me

Comment: There is a way to minimize the browser, however it will flash on screen briefly. The only way to achieve what you want is to run in headless mode. Why doesn't headless mode work for you?

Comment: because headless mode has a major disadvantage of not being able
clicks and sometimes i need to see the info show up in chrome too, 2 months ago i achieved the above goal but now they keep flashing and i put the software on another machine sometimes it works , thank you very much I will figure it out later and post it here.